# How to split data matrix into 3 parts

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, data-analysis

I have the following data x-y-data block x in [390, 1669] and y in [377, 751]. I have the value of the central row y=597. I want to split my data into 3 parts, a central (row 397), an upper (rows 598-751) and a lower part (rows 377-596). I want to automise the function to find the upper bounds for y_max and y_min and don't put them in manually.

```
def split_data(y_cent_index, data):
    '''splitting data matrix into upper, central and lower part'''
    center_row = data[y_cent_index,:]
    y_max_index = 
    y_min_index = ?
    upper_rows = data[y_cent_index+i,:]
    lower_rows = data[y_cent_index-i,:]
    return center_rows, upper_rows, lower_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to finde the indices of the biggest and the smallest element in your data?
The you would need to use the [function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) `argmax` in numpy (`argmin` respectively)

```
y_max_index = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(data, axis=None), data.shape)
y_min_index = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(data, axis=None), data.shape)
```

This would return tuples for the indices, if you just want to get the `y` part of the index, just access the second value of the tuples.

Comment: the output i get for the tuples y_max_index are (595, 119) and for y_min_index (227, 1702). These dont correspond to my boundary values I have for the index of the y-rows (like in my question 377 and 751. Is there a easier way to split this data into these 3 parts

Comment: Can you present an simple example of how you data lokks and what values you want to get from your data? It's a bit hard to understand.